# module 'random' has no attribute 'random'

Tags: python

I have read some other questions from stackoverflow, all they need to do it change file name to something else, but my file name is different already:

```
import random

x = random.random()

print(x)
```

and I got error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "math.py", line 1, in <module>
    import random
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 42, in <module>
    from math import log as _log, exp as _exp, pi as _pi, e as _e, ceil as _ceil
  File "/Users/pgao/Documents/Python Project/math.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = random.random()
AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'random'
```

please help me with this simply question, i am selfstudy python language recently. thanks.

Comment: Try doing `random.uniform(0,1)` maybe. This will give a random float between 0 and 1. Or `random.randint(lower, higher)` where lower and higher are integers for a random integer.

Comment: Your file is named `math.py`, and it gets imported instead of the math module of the standard library. Rename it, and don't use names of standard modules for any of your files.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `random` module imports the `math` module, and since you named your own source file `math.py` it's what will be imported.

Rename your source file to something else.

Answer (score 2):

On the contrary, you've managed to shoot yourself in the foot by naming your file not `random.py` but `math.py`, which is also a builtin, and which `random` imports.

The traceback is exactly correct (thanks for including it!).  When `random` tries to figure out what it is defined as, it imports `math`, which resolves to your original file.  Your original file then tries to figure out what it is (again), but there is a placeholder for `random` (only 42 lines are evaluated so far), and it doesn't have any `random.random` attribute.

Comment: Hi thanks for the full explanation, it helps a lot for my dummy mistake. it works. appreciate it.